# Spark DataFrame select null value

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataframe with few columns as null. I need to create a new dataframe , adding a new column "error_desc" which will mention all the columns with null values for every row. I need to do this dynamically without mentioning each column name.

eg: if my dataframe is below

```
+-----+------+------+
|Rowid|Record|Value |
+-----+------+------+
|    1|     a|     b|
|    2|  null|     d|
|    3|     m|  null|
+-----+------+------+
```

my final dataframe should be

```
+-----+------+-----+--------------+
|Rowid|Record|Value|    error_desc|
+-----+------+-----+--------------+
|    1|     a|    b|          null|
|    2|  null|    d|record is null|
|    3|     m| null| value is null|
+-----+------+-----+--------------+
```

Comment: can you provide sample input dataframe and also format as a code it so that we can understand your issue.

Comment: Rowid Record Value 1 a b 2 null d 3 m null

Comment: I  have edit your question format for better understanding, Please commit it

Comment: @Nikk done.. can you help?

Comment: these values are from files which I am reading dynamically.. so I don't want to write column names in the code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added few more rows in **Input DataFrame** to cover more cases. You do not required to hard code any column. Use below `UDF`, it will give your desire output.

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction

scala> df.show()
+-----+------+-----+
|Rowid|Record|Value|
+-----+------+-----+
|    1|     a|    b|
|    2|  null|    d|
|    3|     m| null|
|    4|  null|    d|
|    5|  null| null|
| null|     e| null|
|    7|     e|    r|
+-----+------+-----+


scala> def CheckNull:UserDefinedFunction = udf((Column:String,r:Row) => {
 |     var check:String = ""
 |     val ColList = Column.split(",").toList
 |     ColList.foreach{ x =>
 |       if (r.getAs(x) == null)
 |       {
 |         check = check + x.toString + " is null. "
 |       }}
 |   check
 |   })


scala> df.withColumn("error_desc",CheckNull(lit(df.columns.mkString(",")),struct(df.columns map col: _*))).show(false)
+-----+------+-----+-------------------------------+
|Rowid|Record|Value|error_desc                     |
+-----+------+-----+-------------------------------+
|1    |a     |b    |                               |
|2    |null  |d    |Record is null.                |
|3    |m     |null |Value is null.                 |
|4    |null  |d    |Record is null.                |
|5    |null  |null |Record is null. Value is null. |
|null |e     |null |Rowid is null. Value is null.  |
|7    |e     |r    |                               |
+-----+------+-----+-------------------------------+
```

Comment: can you help me understand this - struct(df.columns map col: _*))).

Comment: it is simply struct of entire row.

Comment: how to define a schema for the struct of this entire row? I want to have everything as String